# Is there a National Weather Service (NDFD) Query Limit?

Tags: javascript, rest, weather, weather-api

http://www.nws.noaa.gov/mdl/survey/pgb_survey/dev/rest.php#degrib

Haven't seen any documentation about possible limit to the number of queries daily.  Anybody know?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is not an explicit limit, however they are pretty clear about recommendations when dealing with potentially high volumes, mission critical usage, etc.

http://www.nws.noaa.gov/mdl/XML/Design/WebServicesUseGuildlines.php